# Glassfish appends a string "ejb" to JNDI of a particular mobule's EJBs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, glassfish-3

I have an EAR with multiple EJB jars like:

- module1.jar
- module2.jar

But when I deploy the application in the log I can see that the ejb-s of `module1.jar` are deployed with a strange JNDI name:

- Portable JNDI names for EJB ejb1: `java:global/myappl/`**module1ejb**`/ejb1`
- Portable JNDI names for EJB ejb2: `java:global/myappl/`**module1ejb**`/ejb2`

But the rest of the modules are deployed regularly (without `ejb` ending in module name):

- Portable JNDI names for EJB ejb1 : `java:global/myappl/`**module2**`/ejb1`
- Portable JNDI names for EJB ejb2 : `java:global/myappl/`**module2**`/ejb2`

What makes Glassfish to append that **"ejb"** ending in JNDI?

Glassfish version: 3.1.1

It didn't help to restart several times, delete generated, osgi-cache, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found out the problem: in the `application.xml` definition of `module1` was occasionally doubled:

```
<module>
    <ejb>module1.jar</ejb>
</module>
...
<module>
    <ejb>module1.jar</ejb>
</module>
```

After I removed the duplication, the JNDI name was regular again.